# ViewModel array shows empty value (ASP.Net MVC 5)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.Net MVC, I am trying to get values using a ViewModel.
FAQ class have (Name,Description)
FAQ_Detail class is List of Question and Answer which I am passing as PartialView

I have attached front end page and controller page, in controller I can get the Name,Description but always return NULL FAQ_Detail property

**View Model**

```
    public class FAQViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public IList<Details> FAQ_Details { get; set; }
    }
    public class Details
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int FAQId { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>FAQ</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    @for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {

        var m = new FAQ.Models.ViewModels.Details()
        {
                Id = i,
                FAQId = 11,
                Question = string.Format("Quesiton {0}",i),
                Answer = string.Format("Ans. {0}",i)
            };

            @Html.Partial("_AddFAQ",m)
    }



    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

**Controller**

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Models.ViewModels.FAQViewModel model) //The model.FAQ_Details array always empty
        {
            try
            {
                // 

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

[image: Front End Page]

[image: This FAQ_Detail List is Always Empty]

Comment: Where are your HTML  input fields for the Q&A getting generated? The "name" attribute on each control in the array has to be named in a specific way. Take a look at this:
https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are just displaying the question/answer pair as form fields and there is nothing to bind them to the array in the model you expect. Usually, the *name* HTML attribute maps the client-side field to the property name of the model on the server.
The better thing you can do is to have some JavaScript, collect the data and pass that through an AJAX call to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I pass master model in controller and use Detail model as collection

```
public ActionResult Create(string name,string description, ICollection<Models.ViewModels.Details> data) 
{

    try
    {
        // 

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```